# Preference background and title are not being grayed out when disabled

Tags: android, android-preferences

I got a `PreferenceScreen` with some custom preferences.

The custom preference is defined in the xml with this line:

```
android:dependency="@string/Settings_main_pref_key"
```

the preference with the key `Settings_main_pref_key` is a `SwitchPreference`.

The custom preference is a preference with a title and a seek bar with a layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
         />

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title" 
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >


    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/change_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:paddingRight="20dip"
         >

    </SeekBar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text_Box_seek"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:maxWidth="70dp"
        android:textSize="13sp" >

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that when the switch preference is switched off, only the seek bar and the text view with the id `Text_Box_seek` are being grayed out like they should, but the title of the preference and its background do not change color... Why is that?

Comment: isn't the title the title of your preference group and not of your single preference? That would make sense, if you disable a preference just that preference (not the whole group) is disabled.

Comment: The preference screen itself is just a preference screen with many regular preferences which do not belong to a preference category

Comment: Did you ever solve it? I have a feeling it's related to android dependencies or sdk versions

Comment: @behelit Sorry but I really don't remember.. I no longer even develop for Android anymore (React and .NET core now)